# How to point a domain to a dedicated ip

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, ip, iis-6, hostname

In my domain account  while trying to update the nameservers , they are asking for hostname and ip. I have ip alone , how to create a host name. I am using windows server 2003 .

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean domain account as in, a domain registrar?

Your nameservers need to have hostnames in order to be used.

A way to get around this is to register a second domain and give your nameservers an A record in that domain, then use those hostnames as the nameservers for your first domain.

---

So, if you had `domain1.com`, you **cannot** make an A record inside that domain like `ns.domain1.com` and then use it as the nameserver for that domain. It will not work.

What you will have to do is get `domain2.com.au`, then make the A record `ns1.domain2.com.au` and then you can use that as the **nameserver hostname** for `domain1.com`

Comment: Yes in domain registrar only. What do you mean by register second domain . Could you please elaborate

Comment: I tried creating A record in my another domain name and updated the nameserver to ns1.anotherdomain.com and ip  , now ns1.anotherdomain.com is working , but still actual domain is not wokring